# What is the use of \clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

Tags: clearpage

I saw the command `\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}` on a project and I didn't understand clearly what it was doing so I tried to use it in a minimal project. If I create document of class book I get numbers in the header at the right on odd pages and at the left on even pages.

If I put the command before including `fun-1.tex` file it will hide the header number of that file. Here is `main.tex` showing that:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}

\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\include{fun-1}

\include{fun-2}

\include{fun-3}

\include{fun-4}

\end{document}
```

If I put the command after the include `fun-1.tex` file it will add a blank page after this `fun-1` file and that blank page will increase count number despite that page having no number. `main.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}

\include{fun-1}

\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\include{fun-2}

\include{fun-3}

\include{fun-4}

\end{document}
```

The other files:

`fun-1.tex`:

```
This is fun-1
```

`fun-2.tex`:

```
This is fun-2
```

`fun-3.tex`:

```
This is fun-3
```

`fun-4.tex`:

```
This is fun-4
```

I would like to know how this command works and where it is useful. It's the first time I see two commands inside curly braces, I don't quite get what is going on there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! One shouldn't be advised to use that thing, because `\usepackage{emptypage}` is much easier. Good question nonetheless.

Comment: The curly braces are grouping the two commands. It's the same as if you write `{\bfseries this is a group}`. They are not any argument to `\clearpage` if you thought that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's what the commands are supposed to do.

1. `\clearpage` ends the current page and prepares LaTeX to build a new one
2. `{` opens a group
3. `\thispagestyle{empty}` tells LaTeX to avoid adorning the current page with headers and footers
4. `\cleardoublepage` tells LaTeX to issue a new page if the current one (the fresh page initiated after `\clearpage`) is odd numbered
5. `}` closes the group

What happens is that if the fresh page is odd numbered, `\cleardoublepage` does add a new page, which will be empty; otherwise, the effect of `\thispagestyle{empty}` will finish as soon as `}` is processed, so if the page is even numbered, nothing happens.

Anyway, it's much easier to add

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

in the document preamble, rather than

```
\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
```

before starting each chapter.

Comment: Should `\cleardoublepage` end on an odd or even number?  On my computer, this macro is (almost) `\clearpage \ifodd \c@page \else \hbox {}\newpage \fi`, i.e. "clear page ; if page number is *even* (is not odd), clear another page" — so I'm left on an odd numbered page.  Isn't it?

Comment: @ryolait Yes, that's the idea: after `\cleardoublepage` the next page will be odd-numbered (provided `twoside` is in effect).